# Remove ErrorTemplate from DataGridTemplateColumn ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I find that the `ContentPresenter` used to display the content of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` displays the default `ErrorTemplate` when the row's item contains validation errors.  I can't see any direct way to prevent this.  Any ideas?

Here is my first attempt to ensure there is no validation error template displayed:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="70" Header="Enabled" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled.Value}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style >
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image: Example]

Using Snoop I see that the cell contains a `ContentPresenter` that is displaying the validation error.

I find I can disable this only by removing the error template on all content presenters in the data grid as such:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Is there a way to this that only affects the single `DataGridTemplateColumn`?

This post seems similar:
[DataGridCell Validation.ErrorTemplate ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721960/datagridcell-validation-errortemplate-ignored)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.  Adding a resource style that targets the `ContentPresenter` from within the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle` solves the problem.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me. I have an adorner coming out of nowhere... Why is this not easier?

Comment: You sir are a hero :)